# How do I check if a date in format "yyyymmdd" is a weekday or not?

Tags: date, dayofweek

My program accepts date in the format of "yyyymmdd", I don't know how to check if it's a weekday or not. I've seen ppl using `$(date +%u) -gt 5` or `"$(date +%a)" in Sat|Sun echo "weekend"` in other threads, but that ${date} is like `Tue Nov 22 14:16:35 EST 2011` I guess. So is there a good way to convert "yyyymmdd" to ${date} format? Or is there a simple way to check if "yyyymmdd" is a weekday or not? Any language is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* language? In Java I'd use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or Joda Time's [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). In C# I'd either use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/)'s [`LocalDatePattern`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_Text_LocalDatePattern.htm). In all of these cases, the result is a value which can be asked for things like the day of the week.

In Python I suspect you want [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), e.g.

```
date = datetime.strptime(text, "%Y%m%d")
day = date.weekday()

if day < 5 # Monday(0) to Friday(4)
    # Do something here
```

This is completely untested, however...

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in a typed language (like Java, C# or Python), you'd 1) initialize your "time" to a language-specific "timedate" type, then 2) get the 'day-of-week" from some method of that time.

It looks like you're using Bourne shell.  Which is an untyped language, with no native date/time functions.

Here's one possible solution:

http://unix.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/shellscript-l/day-of-week-bash-script-2018531

Here are several time/timing related things you can do in the (Linux) Bourne shell:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html